# How to print something on screen

Tags: c++, c

The question is how to print something on screen without using variables provided user inputs data but not stored in variable?

Comment: Why on Earth would you do that?  Use the [homework] tag if this is a school assignment or exam question.

Comment: @Hans Passant:: I guess you have not met Interviewers who also like know `How many headers files are there in Turbo C`. I guess this was asked in some crazy interview.

Comment: @Sadique: really? *"headers in Turbo C"* ??? I'm impressed :(  ---  Oh, welcome to SO :)

Comment: @pmg:: wonder if you got my joke. anyways.

Comment: That was a joke? I guess it's getting late for me ...

Comment: @pmg:: I guess it was supposed to be.

Comment: Why is this tagged with both c++ and c?

Answer (score 1):

I think you were supposed to use the stl copy algorithm:

```
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin), istream_iterator<string>(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

The relevant stl doc is http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/copy.html

Answer (score -3):

I think you're looking for this.

```
using namespace std;

cout<<"Enter something: ";
cin>>inputvar;
```

Comment: -1: "...without using variables..."

Answer (score -3):

Start with

```
putchar(getchar());
```

then work from there.